# Add custom validator to specific file type in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, validation, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, custom-validators

I created a custom editor for my file type and now I need to add validation to it to display errors in the `Problems` view, so first I created a new marker type:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers"
    id="my.marker"
    name="My Marker">
    <super
        type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker">
    </super>
    <persistent
        value="true">
    </persistent>
</extension>
```

Then I added the validator:

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.wst.validation.validatorV2"
    id="my.validator"
    name="My Validator">
    <validator
        class="com.test.MyValidator"
        markerId="my.marker"
        build="true"
        manual="true">
        <include>
            <rules>
                <fileext
                    ext="mpe">
                </fileext>
            </rules>
        </include>
    </validator>
</extension>
```

Finally I created the `MyValidator` class that extends `AbstractValidator`, then I overrided the `validate` method, but looks like this class/method is never even invoked, breakpoints in it are not hit:

```
public class MyValidator extends AbstractValidator {
    @Override
    public ValidationResult validate(ValidationEvent event, ValidationState state, IProgressMonitor monitor) {
        // Validation logic
    }
}
```

[image]

Is this the correct way to add validation to a file? Not sure if I should use builders as I'm not building anything and looks like builders are attached to an specific project nature and I need the validation to be attached to a file type regardless of the type of project it is in.

UPDATE

Looks like the validate method is only called when I right click the file > Validate, I thought the validation will happen automatically when the file is modified, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does the workspace project containing the file have the Validation Builder installed?

Comment: I don't think it has a Validation Builder, how can I add it?

Comment: Bring up the project's Properties dialog and go to its Validation page.

Comment: Please see my update, in the Validation page I can see my validator but I don't see an option to enable a Build Validator

Comment: Then are automatic builds enabled?

Comment: Yes, the "Build Automatically" checkbox is selected, but the "Build Project" and "Build All" options are actually disabled so I can't manually select them

Comment: That part makes sense. Automatic builds means you're either built or in the process of building. At this point you'll need to look at callers of that method and see why they're not calling yours specifically.